# piping grep to another grep doesn't work as expected

Tags: command-line, grep

I'm using grep on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.

I want to get player movements from  gnuchess game by using grep each turn.
The first command i used is this :

`gnuchess -mq | grep -a "Black ([0-9][0-9]*) : [0-9][0-9]*. [a-z][0-9]" | grep "[a-z][0-9]"`

for the first grep, if movements are 'e3' and 'e5', the output is :

**Black (1) : 1. e5**

I expect the second grep give me **e5** but it doesn't. Output is blank.

Yet when i redirect gnuchess output to a file and use the same command it works and shows **e5**.
Why?

**Edit**:

The problem was with **output buffering**.
Added my answer below.

Comment: @K7AAY  Edited my post. I found the problem and wrote my answer but can't verify it for 2 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turning off output buffering did the work.

`gnuchess -mq  | stdbuf  -o0  grep -a "Black ([0-9][0-9]*) : [0-9][0-9]*. [a-z][0-9]" | grep -o "[a-z][0-9]"`

For more information: [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)

Answer (score -1):

`grep` returns the whole line where it finds a match, so the behaviour you experience is the expected one.

If you are sure that what you want is the fifth token of the string, you can use `awk`:

```
gnuchess -mq | grep -a "Black ([0-9][0-9]*) : [0-9][0-9]*. [a-z][0-9]" | awk '{print $5}'
```

For example: `echo 'Black (1) : 1. e5' | grep -a "Black ([0-9][0-9]*) : [0-9][0-9]*. [a-z][0-9]" | awk '{print $5}'` returns only `e5`.

Comment: Still it doesn't work. Your example works but on gnuchess it doesn't. If i remove awk, output is 'Black (1) : 1. e5' though.